# Dirty data in dbms and degree of isolation?

Tags: database

hi all i want to know that what actually  dirty data  means in dbms.

how can be calculate degree of isolation of a transaction(programm)in dbms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably mean is "dirty read". This is what you can get when using the transaction isolation level '[read uncommitted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#READ_UNCOMMITTED_.28dirty_reads.29)'. In the same Wikipedia page you will find more information about transaction isolation levels. But be aware that some databases support [multi-version concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), where things are a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty data refers to data that contains erroneous information. It may also be used when referring to data that is in memory and not yet loaded into a database. The complete removal of dirty data from a source is impractical or virtually impossible.Dirty data can be caused by a number of factors including duplicate records, incomplete or outdated data, and the improper parsing of record fields from disparate systems.
The following data can be considered as dirty data:

```
Misleading data
Duplicate data
Incorrect data
Inaccurate data
Non-integrated data
Data that violates business rules
Data without a generalized formatting
Incorrectly punctuated or spelled dataIn database systems, isolation determines how transaction integrity is visible to other users and systems.
The SQL standard defines four isolation levels :
```

Read Uncommitted – Read Uncommitted is the lowest isolation level. In this level, one transaction may read not yet committed changes made by other transaction, thereby allowing dirty reads. In this level, transactions are not isolated from each other.
Read Committed – This isolation level guarantees that any data read is committed at the moment it is read. Thus it does not allows dirty read. The transaction holds a read or write lock on the current row, and thus prevent other transactions from reading, updating or deleting it.
Repeatable Read – This is the most restrictive isolation level. The transaction holds read locks on all rows it references and writes locks on all rows it inserts, updates, or deletes. Since other transaction cannot read, update or delete these rows, consequently it avoids non-repeatable read.
Serializable – This is the Highest isolation level. A serializable execution is guaranteed to be serializable. Serializable execution is defined to be an execution of operations in which concurrently executing transactions appears to be serially executing.